# Filtering GeoServer GetFeatureInfo request

Tags: geoserver, jiffle

I have a 14-band raster stored in GeoServer. I use Jiffle based styles to calculate spatial indices on the fly and it works fine.

But when I clic on the map, GetFeatureInfo request returns the information of all the bands.

The request are like:

```
server/geoserver/wms/?REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&SRS=EPSG%3A4326&BBOX=-56.12087982359703%2C-12.437183254414979%2C-56.12083982359703%2C-12.43714325441498&HEIGHT=594&WIDTH=528&LAYERS=layer&QUERY_LAYERS=layer&INFO_FORMAT=application%2Fjson&X=243&Y=263
```

And it returns:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
{
"type": "Feature",
"id": "",
"geometry": null,
"properties": {
"Band1": 382,
"Band2": 343,
"Band3": 592,
"Band4": 321,
"Band5": 943,
"Band6": 4470,
"Band7": 5853,
"Band8": 5624,
"Band9": 6089,
"Band10": 6131,
"Band11": 2673,
"Band12": 1208,
"Band13": 3918,
"Band14": 0
}
}
],
"totalFeatures": "unknown",
"numberReturned": 1,
"timeStamp": "2021-03-24T11:18:15.298Z",
"crs": null
}
```

Is there any cql_filter or something that makes the operation and returns only the spatial index value?

Comment: what happens if you don't use JSON as the output format?

Comment: Results for FeatureType 'layer':
--------------------------------------------
Band1 = 382.0
Band2 = 343.0
Band3 = 592.0
Band4 = 321.0
Band5 = 943.0
Band6 = 4470.0
Band7 = 5853.0
Band8 = 5624.0
Band9 = 6089.0
Band10 = 6131.0
Band11 = 2673.0
Band12 = 1208.0
Band13 = 3918.0
Band14 = 0.0
--------------------------------------------

Comment: At the moment I request json because I am doing the calculation of bands in the front, to show the popups properly

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried this but it should be possible using a [GetFeatureInfo template](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/GetFeatureInfo/geojson.html) possibly in conjunction with the [raster options](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/GetFeatureInfo/raster.html).

The [freemarker templating language](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_datamodel_basics.html) allows you to carry out maths.